# Working CakePHP Webhost

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting

I recently tried using 000webhost.com as they are free and offer MySQL and PHP. But uploading a cakephp project, results in a 404 error. This is because they don't support mod_rewrite. I would prefer a free webhost, but I am willing to pay too. Does anyone know of a webhost that works with cakephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn [mod_rewrite off](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#i-don-t-can-t-use-url-rewriting) in CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

Every host that I have used supports mod_rewrite.  It is pretty standard, really.  If in doubt, email sales and ask before signing up to something.  But really, any paid web host should do.

Comment: Have you used any free hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Use HostGator. It costs a penny

Answer (score 0):

As your question already defines, you just need a webhost that supports Apache (PHP) an MySQL.

Search a host that fits to your requirements, and check Google for good companies.

If you want to make sure they support mod_rewrite you can always contact them,
so you have directly and idea of how good their support is.

Comment: 000webhost.com uses apache, as my question defines: it does not support mod_rewrite. CakePHP needs mod_rewrite to function. Since I can't change apache settings for my particular website, I can't change to allow mod_rewrite.